# Connecting NodeJs to Multiple MongoDB Connection Strings Efficiently

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a NodeJs application that is currently connecting to a single MongoDB connection with a single DB name, suppose `mongodb://localhost:27017` and database name `books`. All those strings are defined in `.env` file and everything works as normal. As my application gets more complex, I have to connect it to multiple MongoDB connections, such as `mongodb://localhost:27018` with a database name `stores`, for example.

The following is my current implementation in NodeJs:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

let connection;

const db = async () => {
  if (!connection) {
    await mongoClient();
  }
  return connection.db(process.env.DB_NAME);
};

const mongoClient = async () => {
  if (!connection)
    connection = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_CONNECTION_URI);
  return connection;
};

module.exports = {
  mongoClient,
  db,
};
```

`db` is being called in my controllers utils functions, for example:

```
async function getBookById(id) {
  const client = await db();
  const book = await client
    .collection('books')
    .findOne(id);
  return book;
}
```

I expect old controllers's utils maintain using the old MongoDB connection while the newly implemented controllers' utils for the stores should connect to the new Mongo connection. How can I redesign the code above to make it flexible to add more connections and how to properly identify which util functions needs which db and connection? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you run multiple Mongo instances on one machine? Unless you like to test your application with different versions of MongoDB I cannot imagine any reason - and even then you don't need more than just one connection.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Currently my application is connected to a single dedicated cluster. I need to extend my application to connect to another dedicated cluster in mongoDB. Unfortunately, I cannot merge these two clusters into the current one I am using to take advantage of a single connection because other existing backend applications are utilising them already the way they are. Do you have an idea how I can achieve this scenario?

Comment: Simply create another connection object. However, I still have no idea what you mean by "advantage of a single connection" and "utilising them already" them. Especially when you have a (sharded) cluster I don't know any reason why it cannot handle your entire application.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit In my current implementation, I connect to MongoDB this way: `MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_CONNECTION_URI)`. The specified URI connects to a single cluster. let's call it a `book` cluster. There is another cluster called `store` that requires its own URI to connect to. My initial plan was to merge the databases of books cluster to stores cluster and therefore just connect to store cluster and get all the databases I need from there, but that will require changes to all applications that uses book cluster.

Comment: Simply use another variable for the other connection, I don't see your issues. And please use correct terms, a database is not a "cluster"

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit My apologies for the confusion. Yes, what I mean is connecting to different clusters.

Answer (score 0):

@WernfriedDomscheit, thanks for your insights. I also did some research and it seems that connecting to multiple clients is a common practice using multiple variables, like:

```
const client1 = new MongoClient(connectionUrl1);
const client2 = new MongoClient(connectionUrl2);

await Promise.all([client1.connect(), client2.connect()]);

const db1 = client1.db(dbName1);
const db2 = client2.db(dbName2);
```

I just thought I needed to keep changing the client connection during the runtime, which doesn't seem to be recommended, but it's possible to make multiple independent connections to MongoDB deployed clusters.